# Collection of two objects and I want to store value of zero index and first index in two different variables Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a collection of items of two objects. I want to store the zero index's date in a variable such as `$starttime,` and I want to store the first index's date in the variable such as `$endtime`. How can I do that?

```
#items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#820 ▼
      +"id": 75
      +"code": ""8080"
      +"name": "Ahmed"
      +"date": "2021-12-01 08:57:40"
      +"created_at": "2022-02-09 11:45:30"
      +"updated_at": "2022-02-09 11:45:30"
    }
    1 => {#822 ▼
      +"id": 76
      +"code": ""8080"
      +"name": "Ahmed"
      +"date": "2021-12-01 18:14:13"
      +"created_at": "2022-02-09 11:45:30"
      +"updated_at": "2022-02-09 11:45:30"
    }
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
```

Controller:

```
$data = DB::table('data')->orderBy('date', 'asc')->get();
foreach ($data as $datas) {
    $dates = date('y-m-d', strtotime($datas->date));
    $date = DB::table('data')->where('date', 'LIKE', '%'.$dates.'%')->get();
    $finddate = DB::table('data')->where('date', 'LIKE', '%'.$dates.'%')->where('code', $datas->code)->get();
    foreach ($finddate as $datefound) {
        $starttime = $datefound->date;
        $endtime = $datefound->date;
        dd($endtime);
    }
}
```

I am trying to do this, but it only shows the first date, such as the following.

```
2021-12-01 08:57:40
```

Comment: Give an example of a store query.

Comment: edited my question perhaps it will help u

Comment: `0` for `$date` and `1` for `$finddate`?

Comment: no i want to store the date of 0 index such as (+"date": "2021-12-01 08:57:40") in the separate variable and date of 1 index such as (+"date": "2021-12-01 18:14:13") in the separate variable

Comment: I have no idea, why you are looking for `data` with `LIKE` in `foreach`. And why `$date` variable defined but not used

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add an expected result because your question is quite confusing.
If you want to store the first two rows of the result of the query into a variable, you can try this:

```
$data =  DB::table('data')->orderBy('date')->get();
if (sizeof($data) >= 2) { // Making sure result has atleast 2 rows
    $starttime = $data[0];
    $endtime= $data[1];
}
```